# Fused Lasso with Genlasso package in R

Tags: r, lasso-regression

```
n = 150

g <- matrix(0,n,Nrofreps)
X <- array(0, dim = c(Nrofreps,n,1))
  e <- rnorm(100+n,1)
  a <- c(rep(0,100+0.3*n), rep(5,0.4*n), rep(5,0.3*n))
  beta <- c(rep(0.0,100+0.7*n), rep(0.0,0.3*n))

  y <- rep(0,101+n)

  for (z in 1:(100+n)){
    y[z+1]<- a[z]+beta[z]*y[z]+e[z]
  }
  y2 <- y[101:(100+n)]
  g[,1]=y2
  X[1,,1]=rep(5,n)
 a1 = fusedlasso1d(g[,1],X = as.matrix(X[1,,]), minlam = 3, gamma = 0.1)
```

This is my code so far. In the future I want to extend it and be able to do more redraws. That is the reason that some variable have higher dimensions than necessary.
This code an error:

```
Error: (mak <- max(k)) <= m - 1 is not TRUE.
```

I do not know why this is or how to fix it, please help